# Loops within loops in PsychoPy Builder

Tags: builder, psychopy

I am new to programming, and need some help with an experiment I'm constructing in PsychoPy builder. I have made something that works, but I can tell it's inelegant and there must be a better way.

I want to conduct 24 trials. Each trial will show 7 unique images, then 1 image which may or may not be from the 7, and users are then asked to enter y/n if they have seen the image before.

In my current code I have created 24 separate input files, each containing a list of the unique objects. I have created a loop which shows the seven objects in succession. I have then created separate routines for the pre-trial fixation screen (constant for all 24 trials) and the response (probe image and correct answer manually programmed). The code works, but it is very long, and if I wanted to change something in the fixation or the probe/response, I would need to change each of the 24 trials individually.

How can I instead get Builder to create a loop which contains the fixation screen (constant), the trial loop (picking the next seven unique objects (they are named sequentially from 1-168), and then a probe/response which is unique to each trial (I have these in an input file as follows. Probe refers to a number between 1 and 7 which references the position of the image in the sequence shown in the trial.)

TrialNumber Probe   CorrAns
1   4   0
2   3   1
3   4   0
4   5   1
5   4   1 
...

I hope my question makes sense and I would be grateful for any assistance.

Thanks PsychoPy Beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct that there is a (much) more efficient way to do this.

First, start with your conditions file (i.e. .csv or .xlsx). You only need one of them. It should have 24 rows (one per trial). It will need 8 columns: 7 to specify the unique images in a trial and an eighth to specify the repeated one.

Second, you need a loop to control the trials. This is connected to the conditions file, and encompasses all of the routines (the pre-trial fixation and the image routine.

Third, you need a second, inner loop, nested within the outer one. This encompasses only the image routine. i.e. the fixation routine will run 24 times (once per outer loop), and the image routine will run 7×24 times (i.e. 7 times per trial). The inner loop is not connected to a conditions file and is simply set to run 7 times.

So note that you no longer have 24 separate routines in Builder but only two (the fixation and image routines). Instead of duplicating routines, you repeat them via the loops.

In the image stimulus image field, you can construct the image name to use on each presentation. e.g. lets say the 8 columns in your conditions file are labelled 'image0', 'image1', etc. Then in the image field, put something like this:

`$'image' + str(yourInnerLoopName.thisN)`

i.e. on the first iteration within each trial, the image filename would come from column `image0`, the second from `image1`, and so on.

I don't know how you are handling the responses, but you will also probably need a ninth column in the conditions file that indicates what the correct response is. The keyboard component can access that to judge whether the response is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is a much better way of doing it.

Comment: Great. If it works for you, please accept the answer, as a guide to future readers.